# Batch rename files in mac os x bash with regexp

Tags: regex, macos, bash

I have a specific case of files set:

```
80e505bf3611cabea7de90e2ba-movies-c7185328dd51ef480b7d8c71873fbabf-ultra-low_000005_10-23.mov
80e505bf3611cabea7de90e2ba-movies-c7185328dd51ef480b7d8c71873fbabf-ultra-low_000006_9-87.mov
80e505bf3611cabea7de90e2ba-movies-c7185328dd51ef480b7d8c71873fbabf-ultra-low_000007_10-18.mov
80e505bf3611cabea7de90e2ba-movies-c7185328dd51ef480b7d8c71873fbabf-ultra-low_000008_9-02.mov
```

And I need to write a bash script for batch renaming all of these files in current directory to match the following result:

```
ultra-low_000005.mov
ultra-low_000006.mov
ultra-low_000007.mov
ultra-low_000008.mov
```

The following script I made is removing the constant prefix part from all these files:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Input prefix and press ENTER:"
read prefix
echo "Your prefix will be: $prefix"
echo "Continue? y/n:"
read continue
if [ $continue == "y" ]
then
  for f in $prefix*; 
  do 
    mv "$f" "${f#$prefix}"; 
  done
fi
```

But this script leaves files with the last unwanted part:

```
ultra-low_000008_9-02.mov
```

So I suppose it can be done with properly constructed regexp, but I have not succeed with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
for f in "$prefix"*; do 
  # removes prefix part
  temp="${f#$prefix}"

  # removes everything after last _ and then adds back extension .mov
  mv "$f" "${temp%_*}.${temp##*.}"
done
```